# acceleo get stereotypes' attributs from within a module

Tags: acceleo

I'm writing a module which writes an LDIF file,

I've a stereotype called 'User' defined by a metaclasse that have many attributs (username, password, role,..)

The problem is that I cannot access those attributs from within the module..

How should I do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the getValue operation. In the example below the elem has a stereotype 'EnumLiteralCodeValue' of the profile 'clbProfile' attached which has a property of type 'value'

```
[elem.getValue(elem.getAppliedStereotype('clbProfile::EnumLiteralCodeValue'),'value')/]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your acceleo script, you can get the stereotypes using `getAppliedStereotypes` :

Example (*t* is an *UML Type* in my script) :

```
[template public myrule (t : Type)]
[if t.getApplicableStereotypes() <> null/]
// blabla
[/if]
```